# Closing Application with Exit button

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, exit

I'm a beginner in android, I'm practicing a Project that have a 2 labels and 1 exit button. But when I run this project in android phone the exit button is not working, it won't exit at all.

How can I make exit button work?

Comment: Exit buttons just aren't part of the (intended) Android user experience.  You press back or home, and just "Walk away" from the activity.

Comment: How does a duplicate question have 20 upvotes and 14 stars?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Below used main.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt1" android:text="txt1" />
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt2"   android:text="txt2"/>
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="Close App" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

---

and text.java file is below

---

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

public class testprj extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

---

Comment: where should I put that code in Android, I mean is it in res, or in src, or in srring.xml? I am really newbie in Android..

Comment: wait for 5 min i will give you code.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll update here whatever the output be..

Comment: Yup I tried and successfully it's working,especially when I installed the program at Android Device.. Thanks a lot.. My next step is I wanna make an Application that can send a message. :) thanks again.

Comment: but when BACK BUTTON pressed, its moves to earlier screens :-(

Comment: System.exit(0) is not working when we have activities containing asynctask.

Comment: System.exit(0) on Android???

Comment: is that the write way to write system.exit(0)

Comment: It works . But it didn't close the app, just closed the activity(Particular page ) and redirect to the previous page.

Answer (score 46):

Don't ever put an Exit button on an Android app. Let the OS decide when to kill your Activity. Learn about the Android [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) lifecycle and implement any necessary callbacks.

Comment: The only proper answer out of 4 responses here, imho.

Comment: 6 answers now, this is still the only right one (well, plus the one with the atrocious spelling). Scary to see how many people think terminating an app is a good idea.

Comment: in a perfect world it's a bad idea. if you are not a perfect programmer (which is hard, esepcially in a far from perfect operating system) it can sometimes be good to exit the application so that users dont get stuck in a frozen state (some users might not know how to kill the application themselves). i have written an app for a client that basically wanted to restart the app everytime the user comes back to it. i decided to put an exit(0) function in to start fresh every run.

Comment: as an example (although this is not android): i have had numerous problems with the netflix app on my ipad. i would often get stuck in a frozen state. i had to manually exit the app to get back in. i'm not saying that "exit(0)" fixes this, but it certainly creates a better user experience in times of trouble (especially for novice users). the programmer could still be made aware of the issue by means of exception handling, etc

Comment: Check out this video from Android Developers which explains this in detail. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=631T7B8HOv4

Comment: @EboMike I disagree. Apps having background services that clog network, unessecary notifications, brodcasts which drains battery and can cause worse user experience(clogging of notification area). Yes Android does take care of resources when needed, this however is not good either as Android must take the time to do so and can cause the OS to blink/slightly lag depending on the app, but when the user KNOWS he/she wants to 100% leave the app with nothing running due to battery drainage etc. he/she should be able to. Also stops the chance of a memory leak from poor developers.

Comment: There are some kind of apps that HAS TO be closed by user. The apps involve security, collect secure data and so on...

Comment: I think an exit does have some use; I am making a stealth app that aborts the whole operation after 5 flings and I want it to exit the whole thing, not just that activity. It'd be awesome if it could lock the phone, too.

Comment: Hope it was a comment!

Comment: @EboMike What if its needed to do on purpose , for eg im making a game (in android studio) where the game/app will just quite at certain ponts of stage, and its now users choice to open the app/game again and contnue the progress

Answer (score 12):

i try this

```
Button btnexit = (Button)findviewbyId(btn_exit);

btnexit.setOnClicklistenr(new onClicklister(){

     @override
     public void onClick(View v){
            finish();
});
```

Comment: but when BACK BUTTON pressed, its moves to earlier screens.how to handle that like [session flush]

Comment: @hitesh this code is only for back activity how it work ......no nope this will not work if we are in  second activity and third activity then this will fail to exit . it will work only back ......if we make this in splesh or first activity then we can exit only ......

Answer (score 12):

try this for close app

```
Activity.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: if we are in second,third activity then can we exit directley at this app....i think this is only for back .......if we do this in main activity or first activity then we can exit only ......other then this can not work for exit this will only back.......

Comment: works for only close the activity and does not work to close the app in the second activity!

Answer (score 12):

```
this.close_Button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.close);
   this.close_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
     }
  });
```

`finish()` - Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The `ActivityResult` is propagated back to whoever launched you via `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: works for only close the activity and does not work to close the app in the second activity!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot exit your application.  Using `android.finish()` won't exit
the application, it just kills the activity.  It's used when we don't
want to see the previous activity on back button click.  The
application automatically exits when you switch off the device.  The
Android architecture does not support exiting the app.  If you want,
you can forcefully exit the app, but that's not considered good
practice.