# How to exit the whole application by clicking one created button?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a button in my apps and by clicking this button, all the states will be saved and user will exit the whole application. When user re-click on the apps, he/she should be brought to the main activity. I have tried using finish() and System.exit(0) but both of these functions are just ending the current activity and bring me to the previous activity... how can i achieve this? thanks.

Comment: you can resolve this problem by calling startActivtyForResult() other than startActivity() in all parent activities.

Comment: Have you checked [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042222/close-application) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code)?

Comment: hope these threads helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014028/closing-application-with-exit-button

Comment: here what is  your main activity the very first activity of application or the last activity of application which you quit

Answer (score 0):

calling [Move to Back](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) will hide your application. you shouldn't call `System.exit(0);`

It's always better to rely on Android OS to decide when a app needs to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code for close the application.Firstly clear the activity stack and using flag then use finish() method.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FinishActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
```

In FinishActivity class in onCreate() jest simply write finish() method

```
public class FinishActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
}
```

}